# Read a file using WebHDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

An output folder called "output.json" exists on the HDFS and it contains the following files

```
|- _SUCCESS
\- part-r-00000-3c9a6268-ff29-4a76-8d74-8c867e7f0f0f.json
```

Sometimes it contains more "part-*" files.

What is the right way to read from this folder? I am guessing it should be something like

```
read("path/to/output.json") // and rest should be taken care off
```

Note: The HDFS resides on a remote server

Comment: I think you can use open & read ("path/to/file/part*.json")

have a look at :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN

Comment: Thanks - although if there are multiple parts. I would want them all to be combined into one right ?

Comment: Then you have to do this manually from command line you can do something like:

hadoop fs -cat /path/to/your/data/part*.json >> /your/local/directory/combined.json

and then :

hadoop fs -put /your/local/directory/combined.json /your/hdfs/path/

Comment: hmmm. Sure. Thanks!